# How to disable/avoid xdg-open popup in Webdriver Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, popup, webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO for writing automated tests on Linux platform for mobile view by changing the agent. There, we have a use-case that force opens up xdg-open popup which is blocking the following tests.

Since we run our tests on CI platform, I cannot mock something manual but have to handle this case through our tests.

Here are my chromeOptions:

```js
browserName: 'chrome',
chromeOptions: {
                args: [
                    'disable-popup-blocking',
                    'incognito',
                    '--window-size=400,767', 
                    '--window-position=1050,210',
                    'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53',
                ],
            },
```

[Click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95t0J.png)

Answer (score 1):

The user preferences have to be changed on/before browser start. The handling of protocol schemes can be predefined in the user preferences. In my case I wanted to deny handling of the scheme `sms://`.

To change the user preferences on startup extend the browsers capabilities and specify user preferences under `prefs` of the `chromeOptions`:

```
chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                '--window-size=400,767',
                '--window-position=1050,210',
                'use-mobile-user-agent',
                'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3',
            ],
            prefs: {
                protocol_handler: {
                    excluded_schemes: {
                        sms: false,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
```